# HttpWebRequest (200ms) 4 times slower than browser (50ms)

Tags: c#, performance

Is there any suggestion for my code. I dont know why is the poor performance. 
My code Takes about 200 ms while browser just 50 ms,  as follow:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
request.Proxy = null;
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "zh-CN");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36";

request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;        
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string str;
Stream st = response .GetResponseStream();
if (response .ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
{
    st = new GZipStream(st, CompressionMode.Decompress);
}
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(st);
str = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure that your browser does not have the data cached?

Comment: to compare two things, it might be of use to show them both.

Comment: I use Http analyzer v7 to get the data. And clear browser cache before visiting the target website.

Comment: Is it necessary to use socket directly instead of HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you handling the decompression manually? Just use

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

It 'll also add the `accept-encoding` header and check it again after clearing the browser cache.